# Converting string time into milliseconds

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js, timestamp, milliseconds

I have a set of individual json data, they each have a time stamp for when it was created in this exact format e.g.

```
 [ {"Name": "Jake", "created":"2013-03-01T19:54:24Z" },
   {"Name": "Rock", "created":"2012-03-01T19:54:24Z" } ]
```

As a result I wish to use 'created' within a function which calculates that if the data was entered 60days or less from today it will appear in italic. However, the function I've attempted has no effect. I'm attempting to do the calculation in milliseconds:

```
     node.append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.Name; })
    .style("font", function (d)
           { var date = new Date(d.created);
             var k = date.getMilliseconds;
             var time = new Date ();
             var n = time.getTime();

       if(k > (n - 5184000) )  {return " Arial 11px italic"; }
                     else { return " Arial 11px " ; }


        })
```

I am curious whether I am actually converting the data at all into milliseconds. Also, if I am getting todays date in milliseconds.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Example - http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/84/

Comment: Gonna say it: NOT JSON data!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get the milliseconds since epoch for a date-string like yours, use [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

```
// ...
var k = Date.parse( d.created );
// ...
```

Comment: Date.parse("2013-03-01T19:54:24Z") should do as you ask. I'm fairly certain this answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, i thought so too - but in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/84/ .. the text does not change - perhaps its something else?

Comment: I finally found out what it was! I had the font styling in the incorrect order it needed to be : "Bold 11px Arial" !

Comment: @RozzA Together with the rest of his code it worked.

Comment: this returns the unix timestamp (integer) I was hoping it returns a Date object

Comment: @RoxanaTapia Then wrap it into another `new Date( Date.parse( x ) )`.

Comment: @Sirko then again the milliseconds get lost

Comment: `Date.parse(strDate)`  will only work, if your strDate is in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: @Avinash This is actually not true according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format).

Answer (score 14):

```js
let t = "08:30"; // hh:mm
let ms = Number(t.split(':')[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000 + Number(t.split(':')[1]) * 60 * 1000;
console.log(ms);
```

```js
let t = "08:30"; // mm:ss
let ms = Number(t.split(':')[0]) * 60 * 1000 + Number(t.split(':')[1]) * 1000;
console.log(ms);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you string is in the form of **mm:ss**, Follow the procedure and resolve,

```js
var t = "08:00";
var r = Number(t.split(':')[0])*60+Number(t.split(':')[1])*1000;
console.log(r)
```

Comment: Wrong calculation in your solution. See my solution below.

Comment: Hours need one more *60  and minutes also needs a *60 => 
`var r = Number(t.split(':')[0])*60*60+Number(t.split(':')[1])*60*1000;`

Answer (score 3):

```
var timeInString = "99:99:99:99"; // Any value here
var milliseconds;
if (timeInString.split(":").length === 2) {
  /* For MM:SS */
  milliseconds =
    Number(timeInString.split(":")[0]) * 60000 +
    Number(timeInString.split(":")[1]) * 1000;
} else if (timeInString.split(":").length === 3) {
  /* For HH:MM:SS */
  milliseconds =
    Number(timeInString.split(":")[0]) * 3600000 +
    Number(timeInString.split(":")[1]) * 60000 +
    Number(timeInString.split(":")[2]) * 1000;
} else if (timeInString.split(":").length === 4) {
  /* For DD:HH:MM:SS */
  milliseconds =
    Number(timeInString.split(":")[0]) * 86400000 +
    Number(timeInString.split(":")[1]) * 3600000 +
    Number(timeInString.split(":")[2]) * 60000 +
    Number(timeInString.split(":")[3]) * 1000;
}

console.log(`Milliseconds in ${timeInString} - ${milliseconds}`);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.